# Node Js send File on every Path

Tags: node.js, image, response

I have the following problem. I have an image folder and I don't want to have to enter every image as a response

I tryed this but it didnt work

```
app.get('/pics/:id', function(req, res) {
console.log("Pic requested")
res.sendFile(__dirname +:/pics/:id);
});
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: That's not even valid JavaScript syntax, I'm not surprised it didn't work. Look into express.static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you show in your question is a SyntaxError and I don't know why you show `:pics`, but I will assume you just made a mistake there copying it into the question and what you want is `/pics` as the directory and the `:id` value as the filename.

To do that, you You get the `:id` parameter from `req.params.id`.

So change this:

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + ":/pics/:id");
```

to this:

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/pics/" + req.params.id);
```

But, this could be a security issue because you need to strip out things like `./` and `../` from the parameter to make sure that an attacker can't request files they shouldn't be allowed to access.  You can use the `dotfiles: "deny"` option to `res.sendFile()` to enforce that.  You likely also want some error handling if a filename is specified that doesn't exist:

```
app.get('/pics/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Pic requested");
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/pics/" + req.params.id, {dotfiles: "deny"},  (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.sendStatus(404);
        }
    });
});
```